# How to Find the New Row in datagridview by clicking a button in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm working on a datagridview to store the user data in database(sql server). The question is how to find the new row in datagridview in c# ?

For example: if the user already entered 100 rows data . While he open the application he can find the new row first column by clicking new button . So that the cursor will be in 101's row first column to begin edit.

Can any one give me the sample coding for that pls....

Comment: How you get data to datagridview? Set a `.DataSource` property of DataGridView or manually adding a rows with data?

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how you can add the row, select it and begin the edit in the first cell:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Rows.Add();
dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Selected = true;
dgv.BeginEdit(false);
```

So in the `Button Click Event Handler` you can put this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgv.Rows.Add();
    dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Selected = true;
    dgv.BeginEdit(false);
}
```

Comment: affraid this will not work when datagridview is a data-bound. Check this link: [Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445121/rows-cannot-be-programmatically-added-to-the-datagridviews-rows-collection-when)

Comment: Yes,in that case he should remove dgv.Rows.Add() statement.

Comment: Yes and add new row with default values in DataSourceused for data-bound (DataTable for example)....

Comment: After using ur code it shows error message as "Operation cannot be performed because there is no current cell. The CurrentCell property needs to be set first."